# How to include,for example, a label into an image in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to insert a label into an image to make an interface that allows the user to consult the available tennis court.

I have a date picker and when I choose a date I would like to display the available tennis court in green at this date, and the busy tennis court in red.

So, is it possible to insert a label into an image ? How ?

Thanks

*Code:*

```
<div class="AvailableCourt">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" target="_blank" >
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/TennisClub.png")" title="click to view in a new window or tab" />
    </a>
```

Comment: you should add a new item like `<div>` and give some css classes. Set the image to the background of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to overlay an image with a label (on a semi-transparent background to improve legibility).

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .image-wrapper{
         float:left;
         position: relative;
        }
        .image-description{
         position:absolute;
         top:10px;
         left:10px;
         background-color:black;
         color: white;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-weight: bold;
         padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
         opacity: 0.5;
         filter:alpha(opacity=50); /*IE fix*/
        }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
         <img src="image.png" alt="example"/>
         <div class="image-description">Example description</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```